# MVC Scaffolding: get current controller name and area name in T4 template

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4, scaffolding

I need to have access to the current "controller name" and "area name" in my views when I generate them with MVC scaffolding. In the controller template, we have the following parameters:

```
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="ControllerRootName" #>
<#@ parameter type="System.String" name="AreaName" #>
```

I need similar parameters in my view templates (Like list, create, or details). How can I get access to these two parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In The view.ps1 file pass the parameters as follows for creating views

```
# Render the T4 template, adding the output to the Visual Studio project
$outputPath = Join-Path $outputFolderName $ViewName
Add-ProjectItemViaTemplate $outputPath -Template $Template -Model @{

    IsContentPage = [bool]$Layout;
    Layout = $Layout;
    SectionNames = $SectionNames;
    PrimarySectionName = $PrimarySectionName;
    ReferenceScriptLibraries = $ReferenceScriptLibraries.ToBool();
    ViewName = $ViewName;
    PrimaryKeyName = $primaryKeyName;
    ViewDataType = [MarshalByRefObject]$foundModelType;
    ViewDataTypeName = $foundModelType.Name;
    RelatedEntities = $relatedEntities;
    MController = $Controller;
    MArea = $Area;
} -SuccessMessage "Added $ViewName view at '{0}'" -TemplateFolders $TemplateFolders -Project $Project -CodeLanguage $CodeLanguage -Force:$Force
```

And Now in the View T4 template use the MArea and MController to get controller name.

Below is example

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateP", "<#= Model.MController #>",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            HttpMethod = "Post",
            UpdateTargetId = "Def",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            LoadingElementId="divloading",
            OnSuccess = "done",
            OnFailure ="FailureAlert"

        }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a lame workaround:

```
string controllerstring = ViewDataTypeName.Split('.').Last().ToString();
controllerstring = controllerstring + "s";
```

Then use it as other parameters:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","<#= controllerstring #>")" title="@Resources.Cancel">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't change controller name before scaffolding like me, you can create controller name using same rules. 
At first i wrote a function in to "**ModelMetadataFunctions.cs.include.t4**" to generate controller name from class.

```
string GetControllerName(string className) {
    var lastchar = className.Substring(className.Length - 1, 1);
    string controllerName = "";
    if (lastchar.ToLower() == "y")
    {
         controllerName = className.Substring(0, className.Length - 1)+"ies";
    }
    else
    {
         controllerName = className+"s";    
    }

    return controllerName;
}
```

And then i call that function in .T4 template

```
string controllerName = GetControllerName(ViewDataTypeShortName);
```

And used like that

```
<a href="/Panel/<#= controllerName #>/Edit/@Model.<#= pkName #>"...
```